# numpy - arange: Why does following example not end at 10

Tags: python, numpy

I am beginner in Python.Trying hands on to learn numpy.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(0.5, 10.4, 0.8, int)
```

it outputs :

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 ]
```

I was expecting it to return (as last item is 10.4):

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 ]
```

Apart from above, if I execute this(Understood this example) :

```
x = np.arange(0.5, 10.4, 0.8)
print(x)
```

It prints :

```
[  0.5  1.3  2.1  2.9  3.7  4.5  5.3  6.1  6.9  7.7  8.5  9.3  10.1 ]
```

Comment: `np.arange(0.5, 10.4, 0.8, int)` and `np.arange(0.5, 10.4, 0.8)` have the same amount of elements, so without knowing the answer, I would guess that somehow the amount of elements is determined first and then the step is turned into an integer afterwards ...

Comment: The results of `np.arange(0.5, 10.5, 0.4, int)` are even better: `array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0])`

Comment: This works: x = list(map(int, np.arange(0.5, 10.4, 0.8))).

Comment: @ThomasKühn : I understood your point but don't you think it is a flaw with 
 arange as it is giving preference to number of elements and not last element that we are providing.

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2457

Comment: @TusharKhanna maybe, but on the other hand seeing Mark Dickinson's example, the code would probably crash without this precaution ...

Comment: So guys it seems, it is a bug as Mark mentioned. I hope it would get resolve some time soon. I wanted to just confirm. Thanks all. Cheers.

Comment: This behavior is even mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) (although not very explicitly): *When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use `linspace` for these cases.*

Comment: If intermediate floats are an option, use this workaround: `np.arange(0.5, 10.4, 0.8).astype(int)`

Comment: @kazemakase: The docs are mostly talking about stuff like accumulated rounding error and inconsistent presence of the endpoints, not forcing an integer dtype with a non-integer step.

Comment: @user2357112 Right, the docs do not talk about this particular situation. But the way I read them they say *Better not use non-int steps*, which is the root cause of the problem as you concisely explained in your answer.

Comment: It makes a lot more sense to let it calculate with floats, and then use the `astype(int)` after.  This produces 13 values in the right range, but with several duplicates.  I expect that since 0.8 is smaller than an integer interval.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a pretty weird way to call `arange`. The behavior is undocumented, and I don't think much thought went into it. Here's what happens, at least in the current release, based on the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/dfc3eba72841e95fe2be44e1194dc5f77a1e2ec2/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L3077).

Using the original arguments you passed, 0.5, 10.4, and 0.8, NumPy computes the length of the result and the second element using the [`_calc_length`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/dfc3eba72841e95fe2be44e1194dc5f77a1e2ec2/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L3007) helper function. These calculations are done in Python object arithmetic, and the length is converted to a `npy_intp` integer. In your case, the length is computed as 13.

NumPy then allocates an array of the requested data type and the computed length, and it stores the first two elements in the array. As the elements are stored, they are subjected to usual NumPy dtype conversion. In your case, the first two elements are coerced to 0 and 1.

Finally, NumPy calls the new array's [`fill`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1d592c12ca7f9c7f471aa8d20b538c5cb4f2cdce/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arraytypes.c.src#L3556) function to fill the array with values computed from the first two elements. The `fill` function recomputes the step from the first two elements, so it computes a step of 1 and fills the array with integers from 0 to 12.

Comment: That's a fairly detailed answer, I was not expecting this much good explanation. I will try to understand it patiently to fully grasp from source. Thumbs up!